# Laravel complex query

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm re-working an already coded "crafting" system that has is based off a set of database "recipes" which has up to five items and quantities (ex: `item1` and `item1qty`). Now previously it was important to order the items in the recipe in the right order, which made validation easy as it was just looking at what the user put as `item1` and `item1qty` etc and matching them straight across.

We'd like to now have it accept ingredients in any order. I know this can be done with query functions, but I fear I'm off base as the solution I came up with marks it as a valid recipe if the user has even part of a recipe (say a recipe contains 3 ingredients, if they enter only one of those ingredients it will validate even without the other 2 proper ingredients and amounts). My solution is also quite long, is there a way to streamline it a bit?

```
$recipe = DataRecipe::where(function ($query) use($request) {
        $query->where(function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->where(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item1', $request->item1)->where('item1qty', $request->item1qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item2', $request->item1)->where('item2qty', $request->item1qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item3', $request->item1)->where('item3qty', $request->item1qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item4', $request->item1)->where('item4qty', $request->item1qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item5', $request->item1)->where('item5qty', $request->item1qty);
            });
        })->where(function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->where(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item1', $request->item2)->where('item1qty', $request->item2qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item2', $request->item2)->where('item2qty', $request->item2qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item3', $request->item2)->where('item3qty', $request->item2qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item4', $request->item2)->where('item4qty', $request->item2qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item5', $request->item2)->where('item5qty', $request->item2qty);
            });
        })->where(function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->where(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item1', $request->item3)->where('item1qty', $request->item3qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item2', $request->item3)->where('item2qty', $request->item3qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item3', $request->item3)->where('item3qty', $request->item3qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item4', $request->item3)->where('item4qty', $request->item3qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item5', $request->item3)->where('item5qty', $request->item3qty);
            });
        })->where(function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->where(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item1', $request->item4)->where('item1qty', $request->item4qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item2', $request->item4)->where('item2qty', $request->item4qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item3', $request->item4)->where('item3qty', $request->item4qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item4', $request->item4)->where('item4qty', $request->item4qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item5', $request->item4)->where('item5qty', $request->item4qty);
            });
        })->where(function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->where(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item1', $request->item5)->where('item1qty', $request->item5qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item2', $request->item5)->where('item2qty', $request->item5qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item3', $request->item5)->where('item3qty', $request->item5qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item4', $request->item5)->where('item4qty', $request->item5qty);
            })->orWhere(function($q2) use ($request) {
                $q2->where('item5', $request->item5)->where('item5qty', $request->item5qty);
            });
        });
    })->where('tool', $request->tool)->first();
```

Comment: I'm new to laravel/eloquent. So I could be wrong, but I think this would probably be much easier to write as a raw query. It would definitely be easier to read.  Also, not sure if you can do it in Eloquent, but MySQL will let you search for a string `IN` multiple columns (ex: `WHERE 'Carrots' IN (item1, item2, item3, item4)`

Answer (score 0):

There will more than likely be a better way to do this but as far as making your code more readable you could just use a loop:

```
$recipe = DataRecipe::where(function ($query) use ($request) {

    foreach (range(1, 5) as $i) {

        $item = $request->{'item' . $i};
        $quantity = $request->{'item' . $i . 'qty'};

        $query->where(function ($q) use ($item, $quantity) {

            $q->where(function ($q2) use ($item, $quantity) {
                $q2->where('item1', $item)->where('item1qty', $quantity);
            })->orWhere(function ($q2) use ($item, $quantity) {
                $q2->where('item2', $item)->where('item2qty', $quantity);
            })->orWhere(function ($q2) use ($item, $quantity) {
                $q2->where('item3', $item)->where('item3qty', $quantity);
            })->orWhere(function ($q2) use ($item, $quantity) {
                $q2->where('item4', $item)->where('item4qty', $quantity);
            })->orWhere(function ($q2) use ($item, $quantity) {
                $q2->where('item5', $item)->where('item5qty', $quantity);
            });
        });
    }

})->where('tool', $request->tool)->first();
```

If it's possible with your application I would probably look at refactoring you code and database so that you just have a standard one-2-Many relationship between `DataRecipe` and items. This way you don't have to worry about having `item1`, `item2` etc. and if you can only have a certain number of items then you can just use validation to make sure you never get too many.

Hope this helps!